# Android Builder dialog button onClickListener

Tags: android, button, dialog, onclicklistener

Good morning guys,

I am working on an application in Android and I want to use a dialog to confirm exit of the application. I create the builder with the following code:

```
dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you wish to cancel?")
    .setTitle("Confirm Cancel")
    .setNegativeButton("No", this)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", this)
    .show();
```

I am aware that it is possible to handle the `onClickListener` as follows:

```
dialog.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)                 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    } });
```

I prefer implementing the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` which creates a `onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` method where I can handle the code as it makes the code more readable in my opinion.

How would I handle which button is clicked? I am used to using the `View.OnClickListener` in which you use either an `if` or a `switch` where `view == "button clicked"`. Please can anyone clarify this for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why you wish to do that explicitly?

Comment: Readability, that is the only reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BUTTON_POSITIVE & BUTTON_NEGATIVE to check for which was pressed.

Here is the onClick signature: onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which). So you can use the following code to check:

```
if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for the quick replies. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In  `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` you are getting the int value as which. So you can check this value using `if-else` or `switch-case`  against `DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE` and `DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE` values.